# Event Connection Tracking for automatic unsubscribing

Tags: c#, events, delegates, connection

I'd like to create a class to handle all my delegate connections and automatically disconnect all these delegates when the class is destroyed. i.e. in C++/boost I could easily do this by creating a class with list of boost::signal::connection and clearing it in the destructor. After an exhaustive search, I can't seem to find anything similar using C# delegates.

Comment: Weak event pattern sounds like it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I read through http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C and I'm starting to see why this needs to be more complicated in C#. The GC runs in it's own thread so one can't be sure when finalizers are called complicating deregistration in the object scope that works so well with boost signals.